# PHP not receiving post data from my iPhone simulator using AFNetworking

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

I tried to send post data from my iPhone simulator using afnetworking. I tried to check the php page if it receives the data. But unfortunately, it's not receiving any post data. I tried to use var_dump($_POST) but it returns an empty array. Here's my code:

iOS Code for sending data to PHP (ViewController.h):

```
- (IBAction)onSend:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/sample/"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstnameTextField.text, @"firstname", lastnameTextField.text, @"lastname",nil];

    [client postPath:@"sample.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        UIAlertView *succesAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Post Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [succesAlert show];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

PHP Code (sample.php):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["firstname"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]))
    {
        $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
        echo $fname."<br/>";
        echo $lname;
    }

    echo var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this:

```
// Your http url

NSURL* url = @"<your web url>";

AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];



// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest
                              requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]
                              cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                              timeoutInterval:60.f];

// set http method as POST
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// TODO: set your params for post, convert them to post data and set to requesr
// NSMutableDictionary* authParams = @{ "param1" : @"val1", @"param2" : @"val2"}
// [request setHTTPBody:postData]

// sample file upload combined with post action
request = [client multipartFormRequestWithBaseRequest:request parameters:authParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    // Important!! : file path MUST BE real file path (so -> "file://localhost/.../../file.txt") so i use [NSURL fileURLWithPath:]
    NSError* err;
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathToUpload] name:[fileInfo objectForKey:@"fileName"] error:&err];

}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationX = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operationX setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    // call to external completion block

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // call to external failure block

}];

// run operation
[yourOperationQueue addOperation:operationX];
```

// =============

```
//implementing in AFHTTPClient ( for upload case , to reuse you own request)

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)multipartFormRequestWithBaseRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request
                                         parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                          constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
{

__block AFStreamingMultipartFormData *formData = [[AFStreamingMultipartFormData alloc]   initWithURLRequest:request stringEncoding:self.stringEncoding];

if (parameters) {
    for (AFQueryStringPair *pair in AFQueryStringPairsFromDictionary(parameters)) {
        NSData *data = nil;
        if ([pair.value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
            data = pair.value;
        } else if ([pair.value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            data = [NSData data];
        } else {
            data = [[pair.value description] dataUsingEncoding:self.stringEncoding];
        }

        if (data) {
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:data name:[pair.field description]];
        }
    }
}

if (block) {
    block(formData);
}

return [formData requestByFinalizingMultipartFormData];
```

}

Comment: Hi, I've used the iOS code that I've provided many times like sending post data to a third party api like Nexmo and it's working well. My problem is that I can't get it work on a localhost.

Comment: it's still not working. My application shows an alertview which means the posting of data is successful. But still I can't get it to show in my php page.

Comment: interesting....
i've read that could exist a "deny all" for the loopback address into file "httpd.conf" for your XAMPP environment. In that case you should remove it or replace with "allow".

Another test you could do is to replace $_POST with $_REQUEST, and ensure that calling that webpage with a simple html webpage works fine.
I hope it could help you